# Magento2.3.5 home page & admin panel is running very slow

Tags: admin, home-page, magento2.3.5, slow-response, loading

I have installed the Magento2.3.5 successfully with PHP 7.3 version. I am running magento on windows 10 laptop. When I open homepage & admin link it takes 5-6 mins to open. I dont know why it is taking too much time. I have used Varnish cache, cleared Magento cache & used this command "php bin/magento cache:enable" but no success. Please tell me how to fix.

Comment: Are you doing XAMPP/WAMP? Those are not supported anymore. You need to either use Linux or use Docker + WSL2. Here are the docs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Comment: You can follow a tutorial from here to get docker working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QTXRYKRldiU

You will need to move that all under WSL2 to get it working better.

Comment: I a, using XAMP with PHP 7.3 & Why it is not supported.

Comment: Team at Magento decided not to support it. Mac OS also not supported. I recommend using Docker + WSL2. Just follow that tutorial and you should be up and running soon.

Comment: Ok I will check & get back to you. Is this the main reason my magento2 is working so slow?

Comment: Yes, when I tried to run in on XAMPP it wouldnt even show a page. I believe it has something to do with generating the theme. You can try running php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f to see if it will generate a theme for you. But again, it wont run as needed. I spent 1-2 months trying to figure out whats wrong and ended up just going with Docker + WSL2

Comment: Ok what is the system requirements to run docker +WSL2?

Comment: Whatever Magento says: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

I'm using 6 core intel without hyperthreading with 32GB ram. 16GB should be enough too. 

Check that youtube tutorial and if you want to understand what they are doing with docker-compose check out this tutorial: https://tech.osteel.me/posts/docker-for-local-web-development-part-1-a-basic-lemp-stack#nginx

Comment: Ok I have only 2GB RAM laptop with windows 10 installed.

Comment: That's not going to work unfortunately. Might as well install Linux instead of Windows. Even then it will not be enough. Get a better machine.

Comment: What if I run magento2 online by taking hosting domain. Will it work?

Comment: I honestly dont know. I think Magento 2 allows for 2GB hosting to run it. But it would be pretty slow and only for 1 person admin team. You need to put some research into it. Unfortunately M2 is much more demanding. Its not made for small stores. I would look into OpenMage if you have experience with M1.

Comment: I have already created on website in magento1.9 but I closed it because of no response, but I have a backup of that. I was running that on godaddy.

Comment: I have the same issues using Docker with a m2 ... it takes more than 1 minute to load a simple page... I'm really frustrated .